# Typescript Angular 1.5 defintion file for component

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am having issues with typescript and angular 1.5, on build I get the error `error TS2339: Property 'component' does not exist on type 'IModule'.` is there a definition file that includes this somewhere that I am missing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latest d.ts file now has the component method. Update yours with `tsd update -o`

Comment: Just note that tsd is deprecated : https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd/issues/269

Comment: This is true but the answer is valid, the type files will still be the same

Answer (score 0):

We had a kinda similar issue earlier today and it was to do with using Angular 1.5. Beta 1 which doesn't contain the component function. 
To fix it we had to upgrade to Angular 1.5 Beta 2 which does contain the component functon.